# How To install kivy for python and its dependencies to build android apps?

Tags: application-development, python, android

I have ubuntu 12.04, I read the documentations and it confuses me, I just want to know what to type in the terminal or what and how to download whatever I need. Please Help.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to install kivy from the stable ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kivy-team/kivy
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-kivy python-kivy-examples
```

Using `apt-get` will automatically install all the needed dependencies.

Comment: You should also check this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them